# DirectX won't install

Tags: windows-7, installation, directx, directx-9

I have a PC that I have clean installed Windows 7 on so that I have a nice clean PC to play my beloved Tom Clancy games on. However, whenever I attempt to install DirectX 9.0c I get the error `an internal system error occurred`

Checking through `DXError.log` I see:

```
--------------------
[09/05/15 18:23:21] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 5738, function: DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn

    Failed API:     SetupIterateCabinet()
    Error:      (1224) - The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.



    Unable to iterate through C:\dx\Jun2007_XACT_x64.cab. The file may be damaged.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:23:21] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 280, function: CSetup::InstallPlugIn

    DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:23:21] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: setup.cpp, line: 1727, function: CSetup::SetupForDirectX

    InstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:25:46] module: DXSetup(Mar 30 2011), file: dxsetup.cpp, line: 935, function: FindDXSetupWindow

    Failed API:     GetWindowText()
    Error:      (183) - Cannot create a file when that file already exists.



--------------------
[09/05/15 18:28:30] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 5738, function: DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn

    Failed API:     SetupIterateCabinet()
    Error:      (1224) - The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.



    Unable to iterate through C:\dx\Aug2007_XACT_x64.cab. The file may be damaged.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:28:30] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 280, function: CSetup::InstallPlugIn

    DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:28:30] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: setup.cpp, line: 1727, function: CSetup::SetupForDirectX

    InstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:28:53] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 5738, function: DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn

    Failed API:     SetupIterateCabinet()
    Error:      (1224) - The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.



    Unable to iterate through C:\dx\Nov2007_X3DAudio_x64.cab. The file may be damaged.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:28:53] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 280, function: CSetup::InstallPlugIn

    DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:28:53] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: setup.cpp, line: 1727, function: CSetup::SetupForDirectX

    InstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:33:38] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 5738, function: DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn

    Failed API:     SetupIterateCabinet()
    Error:      (1224) - The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.



    Unable to iterate through C:\dx\Aug2008_XAudio_x64.cab. The file may be damaged.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:33:38] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 280, function: CSetup::InstallPlugIn

    DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:33:38] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: setup.cpp, line: 1727, function: CSetup::SetupForDirectX

    InstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:38:13] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 5738, function: DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn

    Failed API:     SetupIterateCabinet()
    Error:      (1224) - The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.



    Unable to iterate through C:\dx\Feb2010_XACT_x64.cab. The file may be damaged.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:38:13] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 280, function: CSetup::InstallPlugIn

    DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[09/05/15 18:38:13] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: setup.cpp, line: 1727, function: CSetup::SetupForDirectX

    InstallPlugIn() failed.
```

At this point in time, I have tried:

- Installing DirectX using the Web Installer
- Installing DirectX using the Offline Installer
- Installing *all* Windows updates, then installing DirectX
- Removing the DLLs associated with DirectX and installing DirectX
- Rebooting (multiple times) and installing DirectX

I really don't want to do a clean install, as it takes to much effort to reinstall everything. My systeminfo is:

```
Windows 7 Ultimate x86_64, Retail SKU
GenuineIntel Core i7-4720HQ
8GB DDR3 RAM
NVidia 850M GPU
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was quite simple. Delete the offending DirectX files from *both* `System32` and `SysWOW64`. I always removed the files from `System32` but never `SysWOW64`. Thanks to this post on [Microsoft Forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/internal-error-when-installing-directx-end-user/b7ba731c-4b1f-4143-9e0b-d69cadc4e9c1) that mentioned `SysWOW64`.

It also may be helpful to know that the reason the DirectX Installer couldn't update the files was because Steam was using one file in `SysWOW64` which was preventing the installation.

Comment: Any chance of listing the files that need deleting? I can't see an obvious indication from the log file you posted.

Comment: @Mokubai In Windows 7, I deleted all `d3d*` `xaudio*` and `xinput*` files. When I went to do the same in `SysWOW64` Steam was using a file the installer was trying to update